# Are static methods and variables available in derived classes?

Tags: c#, inheritance, static-members

I have static variables and methods in a class. Will they be inherited in derived classes or not?

For example:

```
class A 
{
    public static int x;
    public static void m1()
    {
        some code
    } 
}
class B:A
{
    B b=new B();
    b.m1();  // will it be correct or not, or will I have to write 
             // new public voim1();      or      public void  m1();
    b.x=20;  // will it be correct or not?
}
```

Comment: Your code is pretty messy - specifically in `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static members will be available in the derived class, but you can't access them using an instance reference. Either you access them directly:

```
m1();
x = 20;
```

or by using the name of the class:

```
A.m1();
A.x = 20;
```

Answer (score 3):

The static members will be available, but you won't be able to reference them on the instance. Instead, reference using the type.

E.g.

```
class B:A
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        A.m1();
        A.x=20;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for spotting OP's mistake in referencing them from an instance.

Comment: I believe that you can reference them from an instance (not that you should); it just throws a warning, am I right? That's how it is in Java, anyway.

Comment: and can we hide them and if i want to hide them do i need to use new key word for method? and what about the static variable in base class how can i hide it in the derived class do i need to use new key word for the variable also

Comment: But i think that the concept behind inheritance is that base class methods and variables are available to derived class and they can be accessed using the derived class also And can't i use it like B.m1(); and B.x=20; bcaus staic method and variables are available to derived class so now i can access it using derived class name and a dot

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: The exact term is "shadowing", and you have to use the `new` keyword to aviod a compiler warning. That goes for any member that you want to shadow.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: Static members aren't inherited the way that instance members are. You can use the static members in the derived class, but they are not really inherited. A modifier like `static virtual` for example is not possible.

Comment: @– Guffa my only question is that when a static method and variable belongs to class and can be accessed by class name so when we inherit statics variable and method in derived class why can't we access them using the derived class name

Comment: @– Guffa ok sir i got the concept explained by you, one more thing sir i want to know that do we externally need to use new key word for the instance variable also to hide  them or simply writing int x in derived class will hide base class variables also i want to know if in derived class we change the value of base class variable like x=20 will it be correct

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: You need to use the `new` keyword also if you use an instance member to shadow a static member. A static variable only exists in one place, so regardless of how you access it that single value will be used.

Answer (score 2):

Static members are available, but you won't be able to reference them on the instance. Hence you must use the class prefix of the superclass. `A.m1()`.

This is in direct contrast to the Java language where you can access static methods and fields using instance references.

Answer (score 1):

A static member is not associated with an instance because its a Class variable or a Class method, you can access it using the class name. It is usually used to retain general Class information for example number of instances created and etc.

Comment: i learnt that static variables are created at compile time b4 execution of single command that is memory is allocated to them at compile time but what about the static methods how when they are allocated memory